# high risk event detected on my hdd

Tags: hard-drive

I'm using acronis drive monitor, and it detected a high risk event on my hard disk. What should I do?

I did some research before coming here, and found some useful information about event id #57:
http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=57&eventno=2197&source=Ftdisk&phase=1

But event id #137 from eventid.net doesn't provide me an idea on what to do with it:
http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=137&source=Ntfs

[image]

What might have cause this problem?
Is it true that the hard disk can lose data when I get this errors? What other solutions can I do to fix this one, aside from this:
[image]

I'm using 64-bit w7.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your post, read Everything below "User Action"  As to what caused it, its hard to say, too many things can cause file system corruption, chkdsk /r will check for bad sectors on the hard drive, if it finds them it will attempt to repair or replace them, if this happens you should consider replacing the hard drive soon. After chkdsk is done you can find a log of what chkdsk did in Event Viewer

http://kmwoley.com/blog/?p=441

.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing what it says at the bottom, the "Click Start, click Run, then type cmd..." part in order to run chkdsk and try to repair the disk?

If you are getting those errors though it would kind of suggest that either the file system is corrupt and needs repairing with chkdsk, or if that doesn't fix it and you consistently get these errors then the part of the hard drive where the transaction log is stored is damaged and the drive might need to be replaced

Comment: yup, tried it and I'm now trying to solve the event id 57. I came to this site, but the tool is only for 32-bit(I'm using 64-bit)http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=bf9eb3a7-fb91-4691-9c16-553604265c31&DisplayLang=en

Comment: From what you linked event 57 sounds like it happens when a removable drive is unplugged without doing a safe eject ("Safely Remove Hardware"), chances are all the data is fine but a chkdsk should tell you if anything broke.  If chkdsk comes back without errors I wouldn't be too worried.